# HTML using CSS3 displays correctly in IE11 but not when render via Tomcat 7

Tags: java, html, css, tomcat

This is weird stuff and I hope someone can help me out understand why it is happening and how to fix it.

My environment is `Windows 7 64-bit`, `IE 11` and `Tomcat 7.0.47`.

I have a file **index2.html** which is using a `CSS3` feature `div {box-sizing: border-box;}`. This is the whole file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin:0;
}

div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#div_header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

#div_middle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#div_footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div_header">
</div>
<div id="div_middle">
</div>
<div id="div_footer">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open **index2.html** in `IE 11`, it displays correctly exactly like the way this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/srhcan/wgshmd7s/3/) is displaying. As you can see there are no vertical and horizontal scroll bars in the page.

Now in Tomcat 7 I deployed a simple Web application named srhtest. This is the structure:

```
srhtest\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF
srhtest\WEB-INF\classes (empty directory)
srhtest\WEB-INF\lib (empty directory)
srhtest\WEB-INF\web.xml
srhtest\index2.html
```

The contents of MANIFEST.MF file are:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
```

The contents of web.xml file are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index2.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

I start Tomcat then open `IE 11` and go to http://localhost:8080/srhtest

But the page is displaying incorrectly exactly like the way this [JSFIDDLE2](https://jsfiddle.net/srhcan/xvrqLo9g/) is displaying when I remove the `CSS3`. As you can see there are both vertical and horizontal scroll bars in the page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your document is getting displayed in `Compatibility Mode`, which unfortunately is the default for local intranet sites, and would apply in your specific usage (presuming that your development box is: `domain-joined`), since you are retrieving the document from: `http://localhost`.

You can use the following to confirm whether this is true:

1. Press the *[F12]* key to open the IE `Developer Tools`.
2. Press the *[Ctrl-8]* key combination to open the `Emulation` display.
3. In the left column, labeled: **Mode**, check the first value: *Document mode*.

If the *Document mode* value is: `IE11`, then my guess is incorrect; however, if `IE` is in `Compatibility Mode`, it will adopt `IE7` behavior:

1. If the document contains a valid `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration (which it appears yours does), the `IE7` document mode should be in use.
2. If not (which can be triggered by a hidden character or newline before the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration), the `IE5 Quirks` document mode will be in use.

### Resolving the Problem:

Update the `IE` handling for websites that are in the *Local Intranet Zone*:

1. Click on *Tools* (the gear cog icon in the upper right corner).
2. From the drop-down menu, select: *Compatibility View settings*.
3. **Deselect** the option: *Display intranet sites in Compatibility View*.

This should resolve the behavior you are describing. If you are in a scenario where others will be visiting a development server that is is the `Local Intranet Zone`, send me a comment message, because there are a couple additional steps that you can take to resolve this issue for those users.

Comment: Thanks. I open the `IE Developer Tools` and in the `Emulation` display the value of _Document Mode_ was `7 (Default)`. Then I checked the `Console` display and there was a message: **localhost is a website you've added to Compatibility View**. To confirm I went to _Compatibility View settings_ and I can see `localhost` in _Websites you'vs added to Compatibility View:_ section. Not sure who added `localhost` in there and why it was added. The _Display intranet sites in Compatibility View_ option was selected.

Comment: When I deselect the _Display intranet sites in Compatibility View_ option, the issue still remain. Only after I remove `localhost` from the _Websites you'vs added to Compatibility View:_ section, the issue get resolved. The _Display intranet sites in Compatibility View_ option does not seem to affect this issue at all whether selected or not.

Comment: When you boot-up your dev box, does it join a domain? In the answer, I mentioned that as one of my presumptions. Without the ability to sit down and go through your IE settings, I had to make some educated guesses about the exact root cause.

Comment: Your answer is perfect. The developer before me probably insert `localhost` in the  `Compatibility View` settings since there are couple of old intranet applications which works with 7 and not 11.

Answer (score 1):

**box-sizing** property has two kinds of attributes:

### content-box

This is the initial and default value as specified by the CSS standard. 
The width and height properties are measured including only the content, but not include the padding, border or margin. Note: Padding, border & margin will be outside of the box 
e.g. If apply this code,

```
.box {
    width: 200px;
    border: 10px solid red;
}
```

This rendered in the browser of **total width : 220px**.

So the dimension of element is calculated as, 
width = width of the content, and height = height of the content (excluding the values of border and padding).

### border-box

The width and height properties include the padding and border, but not the margin.
Note that padding and border will be inside of the box
e.g.

```
.box {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 200px; 
    border: 10px solid red;
}
```

This rendered in the browser of **total width: 200px**.

Here the dimension is calculated as, 
width = border + padding + width of the content, and height = border + padding + height of the content.

So, if you delete this code

```
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The default of box-sizing is content-box and is rendered the browser width and height according to the content-box rules.

More explanation can view at that link also:
[box-sizing](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/box-sizing-secret-simple-css-layouts)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But my question is about why `IE 11` is ignoring `div {box-sizing: border-box;}` in the **index2.html** only when **index2.html** is rendered through Tomcat 7? When I open the same **index2.html** as standalone in `IE 11` by double-clicking on it, then `IE 11` does not ignore `div {box-sizing: border-box;}`.